# Change a document's permissions via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-docs, google-apps-script

I'm looking for sample script that resets the default permissions on an external spreadsheet based on the email address and DocumentID passed to the script. I intent to create a script that can parse information from an email message to acquire the DocumentID and email, execute the permission change from default to *anyone with a link*, then email the passed address with that link.

It appears that perms are controlled by the DocList API and I'm not finding samples of GAS interacting with that API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK DocsList Services does not have a function to change the sharing mode, between private/anyone with a link/public, only to add/remove editors and viewers. But we can still achieve this by previously setting manually the share settings of a specific folder to "anyone with a link". Then, we have just to add the file to that folder to have it shared.

A script to do that is particularly simple. e.g.

```js
function shareWithAnyoneAndEmail(documentID,email) {
  var sharedFolder = DocsList.getFolderById('id-to-your-previously-shared-folder');
  var file = DocsList.getFileById(documentID);
  file.addToFolder(sharedFolder);
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, 'Here is your file', file.getName()+'\n'+file.getUrl());
}
```

Answer (score 8):

At Google I/O 2013, DriveApp was launched. This allows developers to build use cases like Sharing to Anyone with link

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/

Sample code -

```
 var quizTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById(QUIZ_TEMPLATE_ID);  
  quizTemplate.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
```

or

```
  var openFile = DriveApp.getFileById(WIDE_OPEN_ID)
  openFile.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.COMMENT);
```